# Connect 4 Iphone game

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d

I'm new to game development and development in general, I want to make a Connect 4 game. I have made a few simple game tutorials and I decided I wanted to make my own game now. I figured a connect 4 game should be a simple start for me, can anyone help me out how to go about with this please?

Should I use Cocos2d or write it in ObjC?

Thanks
David H.

Answer (score 3):

Cocos2d is written in Obj-C, maybe you meant UIKit. Either way is ok for a simple connect-4 game. After working more than a year with cocos2d i can say you will be better off doing the game with it.

Answer (score 1):

cocos2d-iphone is a great way into game programming without learning the lower level aspects of game programming. I would recommend trying it out first.

cocos2d-iphone has many examples that come with it, which can give you a great head start.

The question is a bit confusing since cocos2d-iphone is written in Objective C :)

Comment: I might have formulated the question poorly, but does anyone have any code for this type of app? Or know where I can find some working code and study?

Comment: Is it hard to code up a simple looking game like that? 
What I would like to do is to make this game and add multiplayer feature to it, so I can play against someone on the same wifi network.

So first question, 
How do I code up the board so it fits with the image I created and the coins so they drop into a column I touch and stack on top of eachother?